# Why isn't Ctakes able to identify : 'colorectal cancer' medical text in spite of using 'ContextDependentTokenizerAnnotator'?

Tags: nlp, medical, ctakes

Ctakes is able to identify 'lung cancer' , 'basal cell cancer' and such - that is it gives a proper SNOMED UMLS identifier. But if the sentence contains colorectal cancer, it just return 'malignant neeplasm'

I have tried playing around with NeContextsSubPipe with different window size and using ContextDependentTokenizerAnnotator ; but Ctakes never identifies "colorectal" cancer.

```
// Load a simple token processing pipeline from another pipeline file
load DefaultTokenizerPipeline.piper

// Add non-core annotators
add ContextDependentTokenizerAnnotator
// The POSTagger has a -complex- startup, but it can create its own description to handle it
addDescription POSTagger

//addDescription LvgAnnotator
addDescription ThreadSafeLvg

add DefaultJCasTermAnnotator

// Add Named Entity Context Entity Attribute annotators
load NeContextsSubPipe.piper

// Collect discovered Entity information for post-run access
collectEntities
```

DiseaseDisorderMention': {'Malignant Neoplasms'} <- when I do Ctakes on "colorectal cancer"

{'DiseaseDisorderMention': {'Basal cell carcinoma',
              'Malignant Neoplasms',
              'Malignant neoplasm of prostate'} <- when I do it on " basal cell cancer or prostate cancer"

Comment: did you find the answer?